# How to open php project in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, notepad++

I have a php project which is done using notepad++.  Can anyone tell me  how to open this project in netbeans please!

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#importSources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File >` `New Project >` `PHP Application With Existing Sources >` `Select the Directory`

[image: opening an already existing files as project in Netbeans]